# REST request failure through filter

Tags: java, rest, filter

I have a simple REST client with some basic functionality, and so far I'm stuck as I don't know how to process those request and send them correctly into the server. So far I've tried this in the filter, without any luck.

```
if (!request.getHeader("/rest/").equals(null)){

        String loginForm = config.getInitParameter("LoginParam");
        res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + loginForm);
        return;

    }
```

And I get the following error because of that deny.

**Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponseFailure**

How should I check that the request is coming from the REST client so I can let it pass through?

Answer (score 0):

I'd normally add header `Accept: application/json` (or `xml` or whatever) to indicate the client wants to get data as oppose to HTML.